# How to unpack a list?

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking

When extracting data from a list this way

```
line[0:3], line[3][:2], line[3][2:]
```

I receive an array and two variables after it, as should be expected:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd', 'e')
```

I need to manipulate the list so the end result is

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

How? Thank you.

P.S. Yes, I know that I can write down the first element as `line[0], line[1], line[2]`, but I think that's a pretty awkward solution.

Comment: are you passing this result somewhere or you just need a variable?

Comment: look at the flatten function described in the itertools online docs

Comment: do you "receive" array of the same size always?

Comment: you don't have to unpack it. pseudocode like my_arr[0][0], my_arr[0][1], my_arr[2], my_arr[3], etc should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
print tuple(chain(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd', 'e'))
```

Output:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e')
```

Comment: tuple(chain(line[0:3], [line[3][:2]], [line[3][2:]])) (note that I put the last two elements into arrays of their own) appears to do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
line = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'de']
tuple(line[0:3] + [line[3][:1]] + [line[3][1:]])
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

NOTE:
I think there is some funny business in your slicing logic.
If [2:] returns any characters, [:2] must return 2 characters.
Please provide your input line.

Comment: E.g. 'abcd'. [2:] returns 'cd', [:2] returns 'ab', I don't understand what bothers you in this part.

Comment: @david: the fact that you posted 'c' and 'd' instead of 'cc' and 'dd'. What is supposed to be in your final list? 'cc' or 'c', 'c'?

Comment: It doesn't fit your output in the question. The slices and the output are invalid. 'd' can't happen for [:2] if 'e' happens for [2:].

Comment: we were not discussing the original input here, but rather the input supplied in my comment - there's no 'e' there. This 'second input' actually corresponds to line[3]

Comment: @David, wasn't that what was being asked for, provide input that works with your output?

Answer (score 1):

Obvious answer: Instead of your first line, do:

```
line[0:3] + [line[3][:2], line[3][2:]]
```

That works assuming that `line[0:3]` is a list. Otherwise, you may need to make some minor adjustments.

Comment: @david: that's the most ridiculous complaint ever posted on this site.

Comment: I see. Deleted in order not to irritate anyone further.

Comment: @David: Heh, now I'm curious as to what it was!

Comment: it would take some effort to explain the true point of that comment, and it's much easier for me to admit that it indeed looked very stupid at the first glance (it really did).

Comment: @David: I'll take your word for it, then ;)

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
def merge(seq):
    merged = []
    for s in seq:
        for x in s:
            merged.append(x)
    return merged
```

source: http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/4930

Comment: wtf? what is this nonsense? I was actually commenting on "You can use merge function". But I guess it equally applied to the edited version.

Comment: doesnt this function return what op wants ?

Comment: Have you tried it? I understand that OP has simple strings there, but change the value type. Not everything can be iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_iterable(i):
    return hasattr(i,'__iter__')

def iterative_flatten(List):
    for item in List:
        if is_iterable(item):
            for sub_item in iterative_flatten(item):
                yield sub_item
        else:
            yield item

def flatten_iterable(to_flatten):
    return tuple(iterative_flatten(to_flatten))
```

this should work for any level of nesting